# Writing XML document with HTTP response fails when content has Control character

Tags: asp.net, xml, http

My website is adding an XML document to the HTTP response using:

```
context.Response.Write(responseDocument.InnerXml);
```

This is working fine except when there is a control character in the content for example "the ESCAPE character" the responseXML becomes null ..!

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have any control characters other than CR, LF and TAB in XML documents.

Comment: Julian...Thank you. I will have to change how the page gets the data then.